# Pandas filter mulitple columns with single criteria

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet with over a hundred columns. I need to filter about five of these to see which columns have "no" in one of the cells. Is there a way to filter multiple columns with a single search criteria such as:

```
 no_invoice_filter = df[(df['M1: PL - INVOICED']) & (df['M2: EX - INVOICED']) & (df['M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED']) == 'No']
```

As oppossed to seperately writing out if each column equals "no"

error for the code above:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df[(df[['M1: PL - INVOICED','M2: EX - INVOICED','M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED']] == 'No')]
```

So you essentially pass a list of the cols of interest and compare just these columns against your scalar value, if you're after 'No' appearing anywhere then use `any(axis=1)`

```
In [115]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':'no', 'b':'yes', 'c':['yes','no','yes','no','no']})
df

Out[115]:
    a    b    c
0  no  yes  yes
1  no  yes   no
2  no  yes  yes
3  no  yes   no
4  no  yes   no
```

With `any(axis=1)` then it returns all rows where No appears in any of the cols of interest:

```
In [133]:    
df[(df[['a','c']] == 'no').any(axis=1)]

Out[133]:
    a    b    c
0  no  yes  yes
1  no  yes   no
2  no  yes  yes
3  no  yes   no
4  no  yes   no
```

You can also use the mask to drop NaN rows for a specific column using `dropna`

```
In [132]:    
df[df[['a','c']] == 'no'].dropna(subset=['c'])

Out[132]:
    a    b   c
1  no  NaN  no
3  no  NaN  no
4  no  NaN  no
```

Comment: Hmm, if use `any()` it return `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`

Comment: @jezrael true, I added a use case where you can selectively drop `NaN` rows for a column subset

Comment: Thank you that seemed to have worked. I did try something similar but missed the double square brackets and I didn't even know about .any(axis=1). @J

Comment: double square brackets are needed to pass a list of columns, if you didn't have the square brackets : `df['a','b','c']` then this raises a `KeyError` as it's trying to find a key `'a,b,c'` which clearly is wrong, but if you did `df[['a','b','c']]` then it's clear it's a list of columns

Comment: I need to find blank values in my data. Is there a short way to ask for either "no" or nothing? 'df[['M1: PL - MILESTONE INVOICED', 'M2: EX - MILESTONE INVOICED', 'M3: TEST DEP - MILESTONE INVOICED']] == 'No' | '').any(axis=1)' gives me a 'TypeError'. I know two separate queries would work but that's a lot of code.

Comment: You could test the length of the string using `.str.len()` and combine with testing with `No` `no_mask = df[['M1: PL - MILESTONE INVOICED', 'M2: EX - MILESTONE INVOICED', 'M3: TEST DEP - MILESTONE INVOICED']] == 'No').any(axis=1)` `empty = `(df[['M1: PL - MILESTONE INVOICED', 'M2: EX - MILESTONE INVOICED', 'M3: TEST DEP - MILESTONE INVOICED']].stack().str.len() == 0).unstack().any(axis=1)` then you can do `df[no_mask | empty]` I think should work

Comment: For the `empty` variable I'm trying to do this with a column list of dates when i try I get `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas` I've tried to parse the string using str() but it doesn't work for me. Heres the code I have: `empty = (df[['M1: EE END DATE', 'M2: ES END DATE', 'M1: PL END DATE', 'M2: EX END DATE', 'M3: TEST DEP END DATE', 'M4: FINAL END DATE']].stack().str.len() == 0).unstack().any(axis=1)`

Comment: That may mean you actually have nan values so try isnull

Answer (score 1):

You need use subset of columns with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for at least one `No` in columns:

```
df[(df[['M1: PL - INVOICED','M2: EX - INVOICED','M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED']] == 'No')
      .any(axis=1)]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'M1: PL - INVOICED':['a','Yes','No'],
                   'M2: EX - INVOICED':['Yes','No','b'],
                   'M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED':['s','a','No']})

print (df)
  M1: PL - INVOICED M2: EX - INVOICED M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED
0                 a               Yes                       s
1               Yes                No                       a
2                No                 b                      No

print ((df[['M1: PL - INVOICED','M2: EX - INVOICED','M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED']] == 'No'))
  M1: PL - INVOICED M2: EX - INVOICED M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED
0             False             False                   False
1             False              True                   False
2              True             False                    True

print ((df[['M1: PL - INVOICED','M2: EX - INVOICED','M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED']] == 'No')
          .any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool


print (df[(df[['M1: PL - INVOICED','M2: EX - INVOICED','M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED']] == 'No')
           .any(1)])

  M1: PL - INVOICED M2: EX - INVOICED M3: TEST DEP - INVOICED
1               Yes                No                       a
2                No                 b                      No
```

Comment: OP stated for solution without explicitly naming each column to compare with No like your first solution