# Select columns that their values are normal

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy.stats

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, the idea is to filter only the columns whose values come from a normal distribution.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'normal1': np.random.randn(N),
                   'unif': np.random.random(N), 
                   'normal2': np.random.randn(N), 
                   'normal3': np.random.randn(N), 
                   'unif2': np.random.random(N)})
```

In this example, only the columns **normal1, normal2, normal3** would be selected.
The selection criteria could be through the shapiro test:
`stats.shapiro`, where, the columns that obtain a p-value greater than 0.05 are selected.

Comment: This might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240762/pandas-filter-mulitple-columns-with-single-criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apply` the `shapiro` test to every column. The second element returned is the p-value

```
from scipy.stats import shapiro

df.apply(shapiro).str[1]
#normal1    0.340504
#unif       0.000381
#normal2    0.117524
#normal3    0.731604
#unif2      0.002847
#dtype: float64
```

So if you want to get those you could chain in a selection:

```
df.apply(shapiro).str[1].loc[lambda x: x > 0.05].index
#Index(['normal1', 'normal2', 'normal3'], dtype='object')

df[df.apply(shapiro).str[1].loc[lambda x: x > 0.05].index].head(3)
#    normal1   normal2   normal3
#0  0.069468 -0.756850 -1.541968
#1 -0.253336  0.136242  1.927812
#2  3.176248  1.909514 -1.185512
```